# Bluetooth tracking?

Tags: android, iphone, geolocation, gps, bluetooth

Is there a way to triangulate or find the location of a **Bluetooth** devices. If so dose anyone know of a good place to find more info on this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you need to consider several issues. Bluetooth is a radio system that is attenuated by objects around it. Also a Bluetooth radio may be turned off or set to non-discoverable so locating these devices is not possible. You need to use devices in your detection array which provide an SNR value and all the devices need to be of the same radio characteristics.